# Define integration response for all resources in AWS ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

is there a way to define an integration response that is applied to every resources of my API in AWS ApiGateway?

Context: I have a lambda authorizer that performs some security checks and returns a policy of Deny/Allow based on those checks. In the Policy i also returns some data that i'd like to write inside headers in the response of my resource.

If the authorizer returns a Deny, i can modify the Gateway Responses and returns this info in the headers defined there.

If the authorizer returns a Allow then my endpoints are called and if i want to return some custom headers i must use the method response and integration response of the resource to create and fill the custom headers with data from the authorizer context.

I would like to find a way to centralize the configuration of this second scenario so that each resource of the API returns the custom headers in the response, without the need to manually specify them in each response integration.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the Gateway Responses section in the API settings, there you can modify the headers for each type of status code returned by any response in the API? This is one place where the config defined is applied to all the resources in the API.